# Sending HTML5 audio element content to ajax POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, webrtc

I'm trying to give my users a way to record audio files and post them to my server. I'm using [Recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) for the recording part, and I can have an  element populated by the user's (webrtc) recording as a blob generated by the javascript library. I am able to record and download the recording, just like on this demo: http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

Question is, instead of downloading the file, how could I include this recording into a jQuery ajax post? Goal is to post the recording along with some data on a  and the receiving server would save the data into a database and the recording file onto its disk.

```
audioRecorder && audioRecorder.exportWAV(function (blob) {
        //Here we get the blob object url, which can be set as audio element source
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        //Here we download the recording file
        audioRecorder.forceDownload(blob, 'output.wav');

        //I can set the audio element for pre-listening before user POSTs the form
        var au = $('#myaudioelement').attr("src",url);
    });
```

So when the user sends the ajax POST, I'd need to add the content of 'myaudioelement' to the data field in the $.ajax call, along with something like value of  , how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Minor oops in the snippet, don't need the var au variable, just a side note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion, it did help me on the right track, however this is how I eventually got the thing working the way I needed:

```
var recordingblob = null;

audioRecorder && audioRecorder.exportWAV(function (blob) {
    recordingblob = blob;
});

$("#myform").submit(function () {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    if (recordingblob) {
        var recording = new Blob([recordingblob], { type: "audio/wav" });
        formData.append("recording", recording);
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: myurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        //etc
    });
}
```

There must be other ways to handle this, but with this I got the wav files stored on my server with minimal effort on server side and no added js libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery's built-in `data` functionality.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/audio/save.php",
    data: audioRecorder.forceDownload(blob, 'output.wav')
});
```

or with POST directly:

```
$.post("/audio/save.php", {
    audio: audioRecorder.forceDownload(blob, 'output.wav')
});
```

Just a note: given that audio files are binary data, you may want to base64-encode it before sending so that it's a string, which is easier to handle.