# Sending and handeling wav file to NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, blob, audio-streaming, recorder.js

there are several posts around this topic but I still have not been able to debug my code ,e.g. [Sending HTML5 audio element content to ajax POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28913175/sending-html5-audio-element-content-to-ajax-post)

Currently I have a client that allows the user to record audio using recorder.js. Then I want to to take the resulting wav file which is stored in a blob and send it to my server side code and store it in mongo.

```
   rec.exportWAV(sendToBackEnd);
}


function sendToBackEnd(blob){
    var blob = blob;
    console.log(blob)
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('fname', 'test.wav');
    fd.append('data', blob);
    // fd.append('data', blob);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/recordings',
        type: 'POST',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        // contentType: "audio/wav"
    }).done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    });
}
```

I have read in several posts that I should set `contentType` to false however then the req.body is empty.

On the server side I have the following code.

```
var mongoose=       require('mongoose');
var express =       require('express');
var app     =       express();
var http    =       require('http');
var port    =       3000;
var bodyParser=     require('body-parser');


app.use(express.static('public'))
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true,limit:'50mb'}));
// app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
// app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'audio/wav',extended:true, limit: '50mb' }));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('home.html')
});
app.get('/recordings/new',function(req,res){
    res.render('new.html')
});


app.post('/recordings',function(req,res){
    var recording = req.body
    console.log(req.body)
});

// app.get('/recordings',function(req,res){
//  res.render('index.html')
// });






mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/sensor",{ useNewUrlParser: true },function(){
    console.log('database is connected');
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('sensor server is running')
    });
```

Any help on this would bee highly appriciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is in `req.body` at server side? Audio should be at `req.body.data` according to client side code.

Comment: I highly, _highly_ do not recommend `urlencoded` WAV binary. That will use roughly 3x the necessary bandwidth to transfer the file.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts so how would transfer this file then to store in Mongo? I got it to work now by using multiparty to parse the formData. Now I am struggling with sending that URL encoded string to the google speech to text API actually

Comment: Multipart form-data format is fine for binary files, as it doesn't encode non-ASCII and non-printable code points with multiple bytes like url-encoded would. But based on the code in your question, it appears that you are trying to use `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true,limit:'50mb'}));` instead of `app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'audio/wav',extended:true, limit: '50mb' }));`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts . URLencoded instead of raw was more a question of what worked. I am at the point that I successfully send, parsed the URL and stored it in mongo. In python I then decode the base64 string into binary and send it to google text to speech. While this works it sounds there is a better way according to you first comment "I highly, highly do not recommend urlencoded WAV binary. That will use roughly 3x the necessary bandwidth to transfer the file." What would look like ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I got audio recording, uploading & storing working using `recorder.js` with `express` server.

### Client

I'm not using jQuery below, only native `XMLHttpRequest`:

```js
this.recorder.stop().then(({ blob }) => {
  if (blob.size === 44) { // 44 bytes means something is wrong. reload to fix
    if (window.confirm('Sorry, no audio was captured. Click OK to reload the page.'))
      window.location.reload();
    else return;
  }

  const fd = new FormData(),
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  fd.append("audioData", blob);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = r => {
    if (xhr.status !== 200) { window.alert("Sorry, something went wrong"); return }

    const response = JSON.parse(r.target.response);
    console.info(`Ok, audio uploaded!`, response);
  };
  xhr.open("POST", "https://my.audio.server/upload", true);
  xhr.send(fd);
});
```

### Server

On my server I'm using express but not MongoDB, but it looks like your server-side issue is more in getting the audio data that's been uploaded. Here is how I do it:

```js
const fs = require("fs"),
  fileUploader = require("multer")({ dest: "/tmp/" });

app.post("/upload", fileUploader.single("audioData"), (req, res) => {
  const temporaryFilename = req.file.path,
    wavData = fs.readFileSync(temporaryFilename),
    bytes = fs.statSync(temporaryFilename)["size"];

  // do something with wavData

  return res.json({ ok: true, bytes, at: new Date() });
});
```